# calculate difference between 2 dates (most optimized)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a page where we can search github users. When username is entered all the repositories of given person are shown.For this I'm using github API. But this is how I am getting updated respository date.

```
"updated_at": "2024-02-09T10:17:53Z",
```

This is my code.

```
<div className="text-xs mx-5">updated 4 days ago</div>
```

So in place of 4 days, I am trying to change whatever the difference is.

Here's what I tried.

```
const updated = new Date("2024-02-09T10:17:53Z");
  const now = new Date();
  const diff = Math.floor((now - updated) / 1000);

  let updatedDate;
  if (diff < 60) {
    updatedDate = "just now";
  } else if (diff < 3600) {
    const minutes = Math.floor(diff / 60); 
    updatedDate = `${minutes} minutes`;
  } else if (diff < 86400) {
    const hours = Math.floor(diff / 3600); 
    updatedDate = `${hours} hours`;
  } else if (diff < 2592000) {
    const days = Math.floor(diff / 86400); 
    updatedDate = `${days} days`;
  } else if (diff < 31536000) {
    const months = Math.floor(diff / 2592000); 
    updatedDate = `${months} months`;
  } else {
    const years = Math.floor(diff / 31536000); 
    updatedDate = `${years} years`;
  }

  console.log(updatedDate);
```

What should be the most optimized approach that accounts for if difference is minutes/hours or just now too?

Answer (score 1):

Optimization prioritized over readability, making you save a few nanoseconds, maybe.

```js
const updatedAgo = (dateString) => {
  const now = new Date();
  const pastDate = new Date(dateString);
  const secondsPast = Math.floor((now - pastDate) / 1000);
  
  const units = {
    year: 31104000,
    month: 2592000,
    day: 86400,
    hour: 3600,
    minute: 60
  };

  let unitAmount;
  for (const [unit, value] of Object.entries(units)) {
    const amount = Math.floor(secondsPast / value);
    if(amount > 0) {
      unitAmount = [unit, amount];
      break;
    }
  }
  
  if(unitAmount === undefined) {
    unitAmount = ['second', secondsPast];
  }
  
  return `Updated ${unitAmount[1]} ${unitAmount[0]}${unitAmount[1] !== 1 ? 's' : ''} ago`;
}

console.log(updatedAgo('2024-02-09T10:17:53Z'));
```

Comment: For better internationalization, consider replacing the `return` statement with ``return `Updated ${new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat("en", {numeric: "auto"}).format(-unitAmount[1], unitAmount[0])}`;``.